# Test coverage missing after upload of Perl module to CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan, metacpan

After upload of a [module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Expander) to CPAN, all testing reports are positive. Nevertheless, the test coverage (usually located between **Bus factor** and **License** on the left hand side) is missing. In my sandbox, I do not have any issues with the test coverage and have achieved 100% for this module.

I suppose that this is somehow caused by improper configuration provided by [Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/release/JSF/Test-Expander-2.1.5/source/Makefile.PL), where the hash element **{ test }->{ TESTS }** currently contains the value **'t/*/*/*.t t/*/*/*/*.t'**, but I cannot recognize any error therein.

What could be the reason for missing test coverage visibility? Any hint is greatly appreciated.

In one of the previous releases, I used more precise description of test files pattern namely **'t/Test/Expander/*.t t/Test/Expander/NoCLASS/*.t'**, but this did not help.

What is also inexplicable for me: the test coverage is computed and visible on [CPAN Coverage Report](http://cpancover.com/latest/dist/T.html).

Answer (score 0):

This bug was reported on [metacpan in April, 2023](https://github.com/metacpan/metacpan-web/issues/2884).  The bug has not been resolved yet.

One person suspects the module version string which is assigned inside the Perl module in one way (`2.3.2`) and in the meta files (such as `META.json`) in a different way (`v2.3.2`).  Notice the leading `v`.  You could try to remove the `v` and upload a new version of your module.

Here is an [example module](https://metacpan.org/dist/Verilog-VCD) where the version strings match between the Perl code and the `META.yml` file.  The test coverage link is there.

---

Note: It was not obvious how to find this bug report.  I clicked on the `FAQ` link on metacpan, and on the left panel, I clicked on the `Missing modules` link.  Under the "I still think this is a bug" heading, I clicked on the "Please check existing issues" link.  The "Missing test coverage numbers" issue happened to be on the first page of results.